# How to solve this non linear and second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'' + ay(y')² + by = 0$$

Here, $a$ and $b$ are constants. I can't solve this!

Comment: There is a linear solution $y=px$ for $ab<0$.

Comment: *Mathematica* can't solve it either. Are you sure there are no typos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + ay\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 + by = 0$$
This is an ODE of autonomous kind. The usual method is :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=u(y)\quad;\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=u\frac{du}{dy}$$
$$u\frac{du}{dy} + ayu^2 + by = 0$$
Let $v(y)=(u(y))^2$
$$\frac12\frac{dv}{dy} + ayv + by = 0$$
This is a first order linear ODE. Solving it leads to :
$$v(y)=-\frac{b}{a}+c_1e^{ay^2}$$
$$u(y)=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{b}{a}+c_1e^{ay^2}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{b}{a}+c_1e^{ay^2}}$$
$$x(y)=\pm\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{-\frac{b}{a}+c_1e^{ay^2}}}+c_2$$
There is no closed form for this integral with standard functions. Numerical calculus is requiered as well as for the inverse function $y(x)$ .

Answer (score 1):

Write it as
$$
\frac{2ay'y''}{ay'^2+b}+2ayy'=0
$$
and integrate to get
$$
ay'^2+b=ce^{-ay^2}.
$$
At this point you can transform it into a quadrature problem, but I do not believe that there will be a symbolic solution.